# Fileupload combined with chosen - selected options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, templates

I'm using jQuery FileUpload (by BlueImp). This plugins uses x-tmpl as templating.
I want a tags input field to contain options filled by a PHP variable. I'm trying to make a prototype by just adding some dummy text.

Code:

```
  <td id="{%=file.id||''%}" class="tagsInput" style="display:none;">
               <select data-placeholder="Type &apos;C&apos; to view" multiple class="chosen-select-no-results" tabindex="11">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option  {% if(strpos(file.tags, "American Black Bear") !== FALSE) { echo 'selected'; } %{>American Black Bear</option>
                    <option  {% if(strpos(file.tags , "Asiatic Black Bear") !== FALSE) { echo 'selected';  }  %{>Asiatic Black Bear</option>
                    <option  {% if(strpos( file.tags , "Brown Bear") !== FALSE) { echo 'selected'; }  %{>Brown Bear</option>
                    <option>Giant Panda</option>
                    <option>Sloth Bear</option>
                    <option>Sun Bear</option>
                    <option>Polar Bear</option>
                    <option>Spectacled Bear</option>
                </select>
        </td>
```

However this code gives me:

> VM34875:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

This error is generated by `tmpl.min.js`.

How can I check for previously selected options that are stored in `file.tags` with `x-tmpl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright.. So I figured out that my post was full of wrong templating.
First of all I had some mistakes with {% %} %} %{ format. Besides I messed up by thinking {% %} allowed me to enter PHP code. Everything within the brackets will remain JS.

This got it working for me:

```
<td id="{%=file.id||''%}" class="tagsInput" style="display:none;">
    <select data-placeholder="Type &apos;C&apos; to view" multiple class="chosen-select-no-results" tabindex="11">
        <option value=""></option>
        {% for (var t=0; t < tagsz.length; t++) {  %}
        {% if(file.tags != '' && file.tags.indexOf(tagsz[t]) >= 0) { %} <option selected>{%=tagsz[t]%}</option> {% } else { %} <option>{%=tagsz[t]%}</option> {% } %}
        {% } %}
    </select>
</td>
```